# Running job scheduler between two different times

Tags: python-3.x, schedule

I am trying to run print datetime every 5 seconds of time between x and y.

By using below code I am able to accomplish the start time correctly and the job runs perfectly. But, I am unable to stop the job at time y.

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime

schedule.clear()

def job():
    print(datetime.now())

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while 1:
    if datetime.now()>=datetime(2017,12,31,1,49) :
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

[Documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-cancel-several-jobs-at-once) provide example to cancel multiple jobs But, I couldn't able to do that

I am looking for something that starts at 9:00 every morning and stops at 3 PM

Comment: are you ok with cancelling all jobs at once?

Comment: @hansaplast Yes, I have only 1 job so its not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `schedule.cancel_job()` which takes the reference of an earlier created job. Or there's simple `schedule.clear()` which deletes all jobs.

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

schedule.clear()

def job():
    print(datetime.now())

j = schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job)

start = datetime.now()
end = start + timedelta(seconds=5)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    if datetime.now() > end:
        print('cancelling job')
        schedule.cancel_job(j)
        break

print(schedule.jobs) # shows empty list, as they are no open jobs
time.sleep(5) # just to double check that it does no longer trigger
```